# With 'AutoPostBack=false', how do I trigger the postback that would have executed after running some JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, autopostback

With `AutoPostBack=false`, how do I trigger the postback that would have executed after running some JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `__doPostback` (I think that is the name, check for it in the source of the rendered page) method manually from JavaScript.

Comment: It is __doPostBack() - Here is a good link to learn its usage - http://aspalliance.com/895